# Designing dynamoDB table

Tags: datatable, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am creating new service which will expose APIs. These APIs are adding entries to dynamo table. I have below requirements. accordingly I need to create new table.

1. As a end-user, I need to add userIds to groups (Each group has unique id).
2. As a end-user, I can delete userId from group.
3. Each groupId will have multiple userIds.
4. Add/delete operations can be performed bulkwise or per individual user.
5. If groupId is not there then new groupId has to be created.
6. There can be 10-15 groupIds and 5k userIds.

I need to design dynamoDb table as per above requirements of API.

I have tried below combinations.

- Comb.1 -

partition key - groupId

range key - merchantId#marketplaceId

- Comb.2 -

partition key - groupId#merchantId#marketplaceId

I am not sure which 1 will be faster by considering my above needs.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you having any particular problems? Do you have a specific question? We are happy to answer questions and try to resolve problems, but please attempt to do it yourself first.

Comment: I have edited question.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL system schema's are defined based on the access patterns of the data as we cannot perform joins between the tables. From the description you gave above you have to maintain a 1:N relationship between groups and userIds. Even if I consider 5K users in each group the data you are storing in a DynamoDB table will be less than 1 GB. [Each item let say store 1KB of data - 15 groups * 5000 users * 1KB makes it 75MB]. This will fit quite easily in 1 partition of DynamoDB (each partition of DynamoDB stores 10 GB of data and supports 3000 RCUs and 1000 WCUs).

To answer your question completely I need - a) Add and Edit operation volume during your bulk update b) What are the access partners you use to retrieve this data and what will be scale at which you are accessing this. I am taking liberty to assume few access patterns a) Get user from a group. b) Get all users from a group, etc. and assuming that you retrieve this data less than 3000 times in minute.

Assuming that userId = merchantId#marketplaceId and above conditions using composite primary key with groupId as partition key and userId as the sort key. Adding bulk data can be done using BatchWriteItems (you can write up to 25 at a time).